# send data from one activity to another activity / fragment via Intents through Custom Adapter for List items in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a beginner android programmer and i am making an Restaurant App that contains spinner of Franchise cities in One Activity and if the user selects one of the cities from the Spinner and click the button, it should display the list of restaurants for selected city in another activity / fragment. How to achieve this through Custom Adapter??

Comment: why do you need custom adapter?

Comment: What do you mean custom adapter?

Comment: Write Ur Code Here?

Comment: Intent will be enough to send selected city id to another activity

Comment: @xFighter because the restaurant list according to the selected city can be 1 or more than 10, so i need adapter to display those in a list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer includes two parts  : -

1. Get the selected city ID from the spinner from the first activity and send it into the second activity. For this part , you can refer to @Chaitanya's answer to pass the information between two activity using intent.
2. This part is about what to do with the selected city value. Relating to your question , you have to get the list of restaurant based on that city and put it in a list View or Recycle View. You have to write appropriate codes to get List of reastaurant  based on the city  from the database or web service. After that just pass the List to here (in the second activity where the listview is implemented ):

   ```
   ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
   ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, <<restaurantList>>);
   yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);
   ```

A sample Adapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
    }

    Item p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
        TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

        if (tt1 != null) {
            tt1.setText(p.getId());
        }

        if (tt2 != null) {
            tt2.setText(p.getCategory().getId());
        }

        if (tt3 != null) {
            tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

This is a class I had used for my project. **You need to have a collection of your items which you want to display, in your  case it's Restaurant.** You need to override View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method.

Comment: thanks, i got the result and is there any way that when i click a list item it should take me to the following restaurant address via intent

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this do the following :

Step1 : When user clicks on "OK" button means

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
String selectedValue = spinner.getSelectedItem();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedCity", selectedValue);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Step 2: Now in secondActivity oncreate()

@Override

```
public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
setContentView(R.layout.b);

Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null) {
intent.getStringExtra("selectedCity");
}
}
```

Thats it!!! All done..

Comment: Thanks, i will pass selected city via intent so to populate the list can i achieve this using adapter because restaurant list may vary? If so then can u tell me how?

Comment: Use Interfaces between Adapter and Activity. and when ever list varies notify the activity using interface.